# How do I update a user created from another model though that model edits?

Tags: python-3.x, django, django-views

My question is based on [this here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67194633/how-can-i-capture-first-name-from-a-form). Now that User.objects.update_user() does not work, how would I update a user if the the teacher whose details created the user are updated.
Below is the view that created the user.

```
class NewTeacherView(LoginRequiredMixin,CreateView):
    model = TeacherData
    form_class = TeachersForm
    template_name = 'new_teacher.html'
    success_url = reverse_lazy('teachers')

    def form_valid(self, form):
        context = super().form_valid(form)
        teacher_data = self.object
        username = (teacher_data.first_name + teacher_data.last_name).lower()
        password = (teacher_data.first_name + str(teacher_data.code)).lower()
        user = User.objects.create_user(
            username=username, 
            password=password,
            school_id=self.request.user.school.id,
            is_teacher=True)
        return context
```

HHow would I create the view that edits the user when the teacher is edited????

Comment: @Selcuk. I got this approach from Abdul Aziz Barkat. The issue now is that I need to have the user details updated whenever I update the teacher details. How would I achieve this?

Comment: @Abdul Aziz Barkat. Help me here.