# Django related model not updating on form submission

Tags: python, django, django-views, django-forms

How do I update a non existing related object  through Django model forms ?

I have two objects: Participant and Emergency. Emergency is a child of participant like if  run the query:  `participant = ParticipantInfo.objects.get(pk = prk)` I can access `emergency = participant.emergency`.

I cannot update emergency with data from a form using a POST request.
Can anyone help me please.
Thanks

[image: ![The participant table]

Here's my models.py for clarity.

**models.py**

```
class EmergencyInfo(models.Model):
    first_name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    last_name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    phone_number = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    email = models.EmailField(max_length=100, blank=True, verbose_name="Emergency Contact Email")
    relationship = models.CharField(max_length=100)


class ParticipantInfo(models.Model):
    first_name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    middle_initial = models.CharField(max_length=1, blank=True)
     emergency = models.ForeignKey(EmergencyInfo, on_delete = models.CASCADE, editable= False, null=True, blank=True)
```

**views.py**

```
def update_participant(request, pk):
    # this function comes after update_specific 
    if request.method == "GET":
        forms = get_participant_form_data(pk)
        context = {'forms': forms, 'pk': pk}
        return render(request, 'core/participantinfo_update_form.html', context)
     if request.method == "POST":
        return update_specific_form(request, pk)


def update_specific_form(request, pk):
    participant = ParticipantInfo.objects.get(pk = pk)
    
    # if the object didn't exist create it like normal      
    if participant.emergency is None:
        emergencyform =EmergencyForm(request.POST)
        if (emergencyform.is_valid):
            emergencyform.save()
            messages.success(request, 'saved')
            return redirect(request.path_info)
    # if the object exists, update it
    if participant.emergency is not None:
        emergencyform = EmergencyForm(request.POST, instance = participant.emergency)           
        if (emergencyform.is_valid):
            emergencyform.save()
            messages.success(request, 'saved')
            return redirect(request.path_info)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your problem seems to be with the `is_valid` method. Replace it with `is_valid()`. So your lines would be:

```py
if (emergencyform.is_valid()):
    #code
```

Comment: Help me on this one, @Sid. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67201794/how-do-i-update-a-user-created-from-another-model-though-that-model-edits

Answer (score 0):

I have found an answer. Not only I needed to call the `is_valid()` instead of `is_valid`
but I also needed to tie the created object with it's parent like:

- Save the new child object
- Save the parent objects (updates the null
  foreign key to a value)

  ```
   *#get the existing parent object*
   participant = ParticipantInfo.objects.get(pk = pk)

   *#if no child object exists*

   if participant.emergency is None:
               emergencyform =EmergencyForm(request.POST)
               if (emergencyform.is_valid()):
                   emergency = emergencyform.save(commit=False)
                   participant.emergency  = emergency
                   emergencyform.save()
                   participant.save()
                   messages.success(request, 'saved')
                   return redirect(request.path_info)
  ```